# The best way to trace LINQ to SQL in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, trace

I have a dbml file to get data in my aplication. Using my app inside with database works ok, no delays or problem with querys. Recently i tried azure and when i use my database it seems it takes much longer to access the data. The application uses a code similar like this:

```
using(DataContext db = new DataContext(ConnectionString))
{
    do some logic...
}
```

each time to consume data.

I know it's posible to put some lines in order to capture all querys each time i access my datacontext but what i'm looking for it's a new feature or something new with visual studio 2012 in order to to trace all querys (time info, etc). in my app. For example in WCF there is a section in web.config or app.config where it's posible to trace the request using system.diagnosis.

Comment: That's what SQL Server's Profiler does.

Comment: It is better to use SQL pro filer if you want to inspect all the queries

Comment: I don't have SQL Server's Profiler